# Geometry of a radial coordinate to Cartesian with bounding points

Tags: geometry, mapping, trigonometry, cartesian-coordinates

I need to find 4 points in Latitude/Longitude format surrounding a given center point and a resulting algorithm (if possible).

Known information:
Equal distances for each "bin" from center of point (Radar) outward.
Example = .54 nautical miles.

1 Degree beam width.
Center point of the "bin"

This image is in Polar coordinates (I think this is similar to Radial coordinates???):

[image]

I need to convert from Polar/Radial to Cartesian and I should be able to do that with this formula.

x = r × cos( θ )
y = r × sin( θ )

So now all I need to do is find the "bin" outline coordinates (4 corners) so I can draw a polygon in a Cartesian coordinate space.

I'm using Delphi/Pascal for coding, but I might be able to convert other languages if you have a sample algorithm.

Thanks for any suggestions or sample algorithms.
Regards,
Bryan

Comment: What are your inputs? In what form? What are the desired outputs? What are the constraints on the outputs? How do you measure distance? A geodesic? Finally, this is not a programming question. Once you can work out the maths, the code is trivial.

Comment: Hi David, the inputs are:  I know the center point of the bin in Latitude/Longitude.  I know the widening of the beam is 1 degree from the center.  I know the distance outward from each bin center point is .54 NM.
The desired output is I want the Lat/Lon of the 4 corners of the bin.  Then I can convert the 4 Lat/Lon values to a Cartesian plane to draw a polygon.

Comment: This sounds exactly like one assignment from my beginning Pascal class in 1982 using Apple (UCSD) Pascal on an Apple II.

Comment: this is not "radial" but "spherical polar"

Comment: Do you have an equation that will give the distance between two points? And which direction are these 4 points placed in relative to the centre?

Comment: Hi David.  I'm not sure what you mean by "two points".  I know the distance to the center point of the bin and I know the Lat/Lon of that center point.  I know the next center point outward from the center (next radial bin) is .54 NM further on the same azimuth.  I do have an algorithm that will give the great circle distance from two given Lat/Lon pairs.  Thanks! Bryan

Comment: Then you just need to invert that equation.

Comment: Sorry David, I'm not understanding....  I do not know the 4 corner points Lat/Lon.  I just know the center point of the bin.  I know the distance to the 4 corner points from the center point (1/2 of .54, so .27 NM further or nearer)..only along the radial, but the part I cannot figure out is the fact the beam azimuth is widening at 1 degree with distance, so the Lat/Lon left and right of the center point is the part I cannot figure out...  as shown in the linked graphic.  I know you are trying to help, but I just do not understand the geometry/Trig needed.  :(   
The graphic explains it all..

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert everything to the same coordinate system and then impose the distance criteria as follows:

1. Convert your center point from geographic coordinates to polar coordinates to yield (r<sub>C</sub>, θ<sub>C</sub>)
2. Convert your center point from polar to Cartesian coordinates using your equations yielding (x<sub>C</sub>, y<sub>C</sub>)
3. The corner points on the right side of the center points (x<sub>R</sub>, y<sub>R</sub>) satisfy the equation

   (x<sub>R</sub> - x<sub>C</sub>)<sup>2</sup> +  (y<sub>R</sub> - y<sub>C</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = D<sup>2</sup>

   [r<sub>R</sub>cos(θ<sub>C</sub>+0.5<sup>o</sup>) - x<sub>C</sub>]<sup>2</sup> +  [r<sub>R</sub>sin(θ<sub>C</sub>+0.5<sup>o</sup>) - y<sub>C</sub>]<sup>2</sup> = D<sup>2</sup>

where D=distance between the center point and corner points

Everything is known in the above equation except r<sub>R</sub>. This should yield a quadratic equation with two solutions which you can easily solve. Those are your two corner points on the right side.

4. Repeat step 3 with angle θ<sub>C</sub>-0.5<sup>o</sup> to get the  corner points on the left side.

Comment: I really don't fully understand your equations above, but this does give me a basis to study the problem further.  One question:  In step 3, how do I get the value of xR and yR?
Thanks!, Bryan

Comment: The equations are just the [Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) distance between the center point and the corner points. Also, you do not directly solve for xR and yR. You solve for rR. Once you have  rR then you can use your polar to Cartesian equations to get xR and yR.